# R ggplot2 assigning colours to a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatterdiagram x, y 
coloured by a factor z (five values)
with the colour values assigned by a palette
I have tried :

```
library(ggplot2)

Palette1 <- c('red','green','blue','violet','black')

p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x,y)) 

p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(z)))
p + scale_colour_manual(values=Palette1 )
```

but I get an error message:

```
Error: No layers in plot
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please provide the data you're using - necessary to execute your source code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error comes because you plot:

```
p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(z)))
```

And then try to make a new plot of:

```
p + scale_colour_manual(values=Palette1)
```

Which doesn't have any layers in it.  Instead, I usually make all my assignments at the time of plotting:

```
ggpot(df1, aes(x, y, colour=factor(z))) + 
    geom_point() +
    scale_colour_manual(values=Palette1)
```

Or you can assign your first `p + geom_point(...)` to `p`:

```
p <- p + geom_point(...)
```

Then proceed as you were.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was very helpful. How can I alter the legend so it says z rather than factor(z)?

Comment: add `labs(colour='z')`.  I'd suggest the `ggplot2` website, book and google group as places to visit regularly.  They are invaluable for understanding the syntax and construction of plots.  Eventually (and usually fairly quickly) the `ggplot` notion of building plots by layers becomes clear and making even complex plots will be second nature.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works very well and thank you for the suggestions.