# Assigning fixed colour to a subset in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the two following datatable:

```
dt1 <- data.table(height=1.7+rnorm(100,0,0.3), year=1:100, specy=rep("B",100))
dt2 <- data.table(height=2+rnorm(100,0,0.5), year=1:100, specy=rep("A",100))
```

I can plot separately each of this set of data. The following command will give the same colour on each graph:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(year, height,colour=specy), dt1)
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(year, height,colour=specy), dt2)
```

How can I fix, a purple colour for one and a green colour for the other?

Besides, when I draw the combined graph:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(year, height,colour=specy), rbindlist(list(dt2,dt1)))
```

I would like to have the same colour which have appeared previously on the two distinct graph for each specy... I currently do not know how to handle it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [R ggplot2 assigning colours to a factor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836389/r-ggplot2-assigning-colours-to-a-factor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))
```

This should help, you also can add colour names, like

```
 + scale_colour_manual(values = c(A="red",B="blue"))
```

Another solution would be:

```
ggplot()+geom_point(dt1, aes(year, height),colour="red")
```